# Display Instant Search on the homepage

Tags: magento, algolia

I'm having trouble getting the Instant Search to display on the homepage of my Magento site. Instant search works perfectly throughout the rest of the site assigned to a custom dom. (I'm actually putting the Instant Search feature in the site footer). Has anyone else experienced this issue placing the Instant Search feature on the homepage (front page) with Magento?

Comment: You cross posted this on 2 channels, please follow the thread here: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/algolia-instant-search-results-on-home-page-of-magento-1/1066

Answer (score 1):

Try this to call a instant search template in footer section

```
path :/app/design/frontend/themename/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <container name="footer-content" as="footer-content" label="Page Footer Content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-instant-search">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="instant_search" template="Magento_Theme::html/yourtemlpate.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. My theme doesn't have a default.xml so I'm looking at the page.xml 

I believe I need to replace the block class and the template path inside the container only, is that correct? 
Also what are both of these components doing, if you could provide me with a little explanation I might be able to come to a solution.

Thanks again for your help, very much appreciated.

Comment: If you do not have the default.xml file then create on the bases of default theme or module.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your answer and I've created the default.xml page as a result.
However it's still unclear what the block class and template paths are supposed to be and what they are supposed to do.
I suspect your answer is right but until I link it up and test I can't validate it.
Thanks again for your time assisting me.

Comment: Have you given the correct block class and correct folder instead of <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="instant_search" template="Magento_Theme::html/yourtemlpate.phtml" />

Comment: Magento_Theme  : this is module   html/yourtemlpate.phtml  : this is folder and filename

Comment: Hi thanks for your help- I couldn't get this working so for the mean time I've hacked a solution together using an iFrame to fire it. For some strange reason, the instant search won't run on my homepage no matter what. Thanks again for your help and I hope your answer helps some people.